# Error Component loading when try adding angular material

Tags: node.js, angular

I am trying to add angular material in my angular project. i have added angular material , below are my files.

**app.module.ts**

```
  import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
  import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

  import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
  import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
  import {MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material';

  @NgModule({
    declarations: [
      AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      AppRoutingModule,MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })
  export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
  import { Component } from '@angular/core';

  @Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
  })
  export class AppComponent {

    title = 'sp';
  }
```

**app.component.html**

```
  <mat-menu #appMenu="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item>Settings</button>
    <button mat-menu-item>Help</button>
  </mat-menu>

  <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="appMenu">
    <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I am getting error while running :

> There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "matMenu" ("]#appMenu="matMenu">
>           Settings
>           Help
>         "): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@0:10
>         'mat-menu' is not a known element:
>         1

Comment: Which version of angular & material are you using? I believe it's just a version problem

Comment: You are not importing the MatMenuModule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to import  [MatMenuModule](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api) to use the selector `mat-menu`

```
imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      AppRoutingModule,
      MatButtonModule, 
      MatCheckboxModule,
      MatMenuModule
]
```